# c++ how to store four 8 bit integers as a 32 bit unsigned integer?

Tags: c++, unsigned, unsigned-integer

I have four integers and I need to convert them into an unsigned 32 bit integer. I am converting an HDR image into LDR output image data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have four 8-bit integers, and you want to combine them into one 32-bit integer.  The way to do that is to use bit-shifting, eg:

```cpp
uint8_t ui1, ui2, ui3, ui4;

// set values to ui1..ui4 as neeed...

uint32_t ui32 = (uint32_t(ui1) << 24) | (uint32_t(ui2) << 16) | (uint32_t(ui3) << 8) | uint32_t(ui4);

// use ui32 as needed...
```

Or, change the order of `ui1..ui4` if you need the endian of `ui32` to be reversed:

```cpp
uint32_t ui32 = (uint32_t(ui4) << 24) | (uint32_t(ui3) << 16) | (uint32_t(ui2) << 8) | uint32_t(ui1);
```

---

**UPDATE:** Given your comment:

> Would this work if I have expressed the numbers as normal "int" ?

Yes, this can be applied in that situation too.  You just need to add some bit masking to ensure the `int` values don't exceed 8 bits each, eg:

```cpp
int i1, i2, i3, i4;

// set values to i1..i4 as neeed...

uint32_t ui32 = (uint32_t(i1 & 0xFF) << 24) | (uint32_t(i2 & 0xFF) << 16) | (uint32_t(i3 & 0xFF) << 8) | uint32_t(i4 & 0xFF);

// use ui32 as needed...
```

Be sure the `int` values are in the range 0..255, inclusive, so that no data loss occurs during the bit masking.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have one small question. Would this work if I have expressed the numbers as normal "int" ?

Comment: @RedionSaarland `int` is not 8 bits on any platform I know of.  On older platforms, it may have been 16 bits, but most modern platforms use a 32-bit `int`.  But yes, this solution is usable even with `int`s.  I have updated my answer.